# finding out when a MotionEvent has finished

Tags: android, touch-event

Im trying to figure out how to see when a MotionEvent is done with an event (i.e, the user has pressed on the screen, dragged around, and took their finger off the screen). In the Docs i only see getEventTime to generate when the event started, but theres no mention on how to figure out when it finished. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is   `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` flag are there
You can check by comparing it with `event.getAction()`
you can use like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //now touched 
                 break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               //your code 
                break;
           }
   }
```

There are a lot of flags, Check this [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: thanks, i just figured it out a half hour ago with the same code :)